# C# regex to match "+99.99" or "-99.99" or "99.99"

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I am looking for a regular expression in C# to match any of these strings: "+99.99", "-99.99", "99.99". The same regular expression should not match the string "+-99.99". Can any one please suggest an answer.

Comment: `[+-]?99\.99`  ?

Comment: @fan711 [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
        String regex = "^(\\+|-)?99\\.99$";
        String str1 = "-99.99";
        String str2 = "+99.99";
        String str3 = "99.99";
        String str4 = "+-99.99";

        System.Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(str1, regex));
        System.Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(str2, regex));
        System.Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(str3, regex));
        System.Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(str4, regex));

        System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Yielded:

> True True True False

Explanation:  `^` will instruct the regex engine to start matching from the beginning of the string, `(\\+|-)` denotes a `+` or `-` character. The `+` is a special character in regex syntax and thus needs to be escaped. The OR operator is denoted by the `|` character.

The `?` denotes that the `+` or `-` character may or may not be there (it will match 0 or 1 instances of whatever preceeds it).

`99\\.99` denotes the string `99.99`. The `.` is also a special character in regex syntax and thus needs to be escaped. The `$` character will instruct the regex engine to stop matching at the end of the string.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Actually I tried with similar expressions but I did not use ^. Thank you for your reply. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[+-]?\d+\.\d+
```

explain:

```
[+-]?      any character of: '+', '-' 
           (optional, matching the most amount possible)

\d+         digits (0-9) 
            (1 or more time, matching the most amount possible)

\.          '.'

\d+         digits (0-9) 
           (1 or more times, matching the most amount possible)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test your regex with some online testers (very helpful to learn regex).
My favorites are : http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html and http://regexhero.net/tester/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to only match positive or negative 99.99, you can use `[+-]?99\.99`. This regular expression will match *99.99*, optionally preceded by a `+` or `-` character. If you want to match any number, optionally with up to two decimal places, you could use `[+-]?\d{1,}(\.\d{0,2})?`.

As usual, if you want the regular expression to match only the entire string, you need to prepend `^` and append `$`, i.e. `^[+-]?99\.99$`.